# Http Action - Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: azure, ssl, cloudflare

this is how I try to the scheduler to work on my azure server, but every time I try set it up as it comes with an error like this:

> Http Action - Request to host 'www.blabla.dk' failed: SecureChannelFailure The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I CloudFlare which makes my ssl, but it would then love to just check my ssl lies with CloudFlare.

This is what my set-up out to the scheduler, which does not make any sense since I have følgt Azure guid to set it up. but it still occurs with errors.

[See here](http://billedeupload.dk/?v=HTWIA.png)

Comment: I don't know what this scheduler is but my guess is that the problem is that it does not support [SNI (Server Name Indication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). But for this host SNI is needed to get the correct certificate, since without SNI you get only a generic cloudflare certificate which does not match the hostname.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich its not work for me on its,

Comment: I have no idea what you tried to tell me with the last comment.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It is such that it does not work and I have tried to see if it was but it was not.

Comment: I have no idea what you even tried to make it work, apart from what you described in your question.